# Concatenate c# int into .jpg

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to concatenate the  src Line 4. I need to put the empkey into the src so that it gets the right picture. What is the right way to concatenate this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="empImage">
            <img src="EmpImages/@item.EmpKey +.jpg" style="float:left; border:1px solid #A4A4A4;" height="80" width="80">
        </div>
        <div class="forumTitle">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ForumTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="forumDate">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ForumDate)
        </div>
        <div class="forumPost">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ForumPost)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You operator is inside the string, it will be parsed as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need brackets to help MVC work out where the C# code ends.

`<img src="EmpImages/@(item.EmpKey).jpg"`

These are optional in all razor syntax, but in complex situations the parser can get a bit lost trying to guess whether this is `@(item).EmpKey.jpg`, `@(item.EmpKey).jpg` or `@(item.EmpKey.jpg)` and the brackets let you be explicit as to which you're after.